# Prefill textarea form builder symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I wish prefill textarea field with my contents from the controller. It's work if I do :

```
<textarea name="parameters"
          class="form-control"
          id="parameters"
          rows="{{ size }}"
          disabled>
        {% for i in contents %}
            {{ i }}
        {% endfor %}
</textarea>
```

But I don't know how to do with :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('textarea', TextareaType::class,[
            'data' => // $contents (it's an array)
```

I don't work with entities, $contents is an array fill with :

```
    file = fopen($newFile, "r+");
    $contents = [] ;
    while (($content = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        array_push($contents, $content);
    }
   fclose($file);
```

Any ideas mates ? TY :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that de data is an array and Symfony cannot convert it to string. You can try with this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add(
   'textarea', 
   TextareaType::class, 
   [
     'data' => implode(' ' , $content)
   ]
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thank for your contribution , I will try later , look my answer above :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer **Jose M. González**, I will try your method later because during this time I founded a solution by myself ahah !

Look :

```
$file = fopen($newFile, "r+");
$contents = fread($file, filesize($newFile));


$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('textarea', TextareaType::class, [
            'data' => $contents,
            'attr' => ['rows' => 100],
        ])
```

It was a bad idea to use an array, it was easier :)